# WCF Server running under Mono intermittently crashes when responding to client request

Tags: .net, wcf, mono

I'm getting a fairly intermittent error when running a WCF server on Gentoo Linux (2.6.32-gentoo-r7) under Mono 3.0 and the WCF client on Windows 7.

**On the client side, I get the following exception:**

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to {myendpoint}. 
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. 
This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). 
See server logs for more details. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host     
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Server stack trace:
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]:
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
  at {the WCF method call}....
```

**On the Server side, I get the following:**

```
OnUnhandledException:Fatal Error: Read failure 
  InnerException:  interrupted
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.RequestStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamReader.Read (System.Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadTextReader (Int32 remained) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.PeekChar () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlSimpleDictionaryReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.XmlReaderMessage.ReadEnvelopeStart () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.XmlReaderMessage..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader envelopeReader, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage (System.IO.Stream stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, System.String contentType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpReplyChannel.CreatePostMessage (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpContextInfo ctxi) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpReplyChannel.TryReceiveRequest (TimeSpan timeout, System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext& context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannelBase.<BeginTryReceiveRequest>m__10 (TimeSpan tout, System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext& ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

It appears to me the client attempts to make a WCF method call, but the server in the process of reading the request has a fatal read error.  The client, as I guess would be expected in such a case, asserts with a *CommunicationExpection*.  But I have no idea what caused the problem on the service side and if there is anything I can do about it since it is occurring on a thread I don’t believe I have any control over.  Any clues to how I might triage this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is throw wireshark on your server so you can catch the raw request that is causing it to fail.

Once you have the request you should be able to replay it with SoapUi or Fiddler while you debug it.

Just being able to see the bad request might make it obvious what the problem is.

Watch for invalid XML, too much data, timeouts, etc.

Comment: Thanks, we'll give that a try.

Comment: Well, lets start with the simple things here first - if we really have to look at http traffic here, Fiddler output is much easier to look at and the extra stuff from Wireshark only rarely needed.

Comment: But before even jumping into these details, lets do the simple things first: which configuration are you using on client and server?  BasicHttpBinding or the new .NET 4.5 BasicHttpsBinding?  Which Security and are you using any Authentication?  If you do use any of these, does the problem go away if you turn any of these off (if it does, that would already narrow the problem down quite a bit).  Did you configure any additional behaviors in your app.config?

Comment: Then, let's look at the method that you're trying to invoke.  What's it's signature (return type and parameters in C#), do you throw any Exceptions inside it?  Can you reproduce the problem with a simple stand-alone test case (that would be really great).

Comment: From looking at that stack trace, a Fiddler trace may be required anyways to debug this, but that only shows that either side sends over the wire, not what the other side expects to receive.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  To answer some of the questions:  BasicHttpBinding (.Net 3.5), Default Security and no Authentication specified, no additional behaviors in the app.config, this issue has occurred on calls to multiple methods,  exceptions inside the method is irrelevant as my methods are never called on the server side when this occurs.  Have not be able to sandbox this problem...haven't even been able to reproduce it in a debugging environment.